# Algorithm: Find smallest contiguous array containing K 0's in array of 1's and 0's

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have array of 1's and 0's only. Now I want to find smallest contiguous subset/subarray which contains at least K 0's.

Example
Array is 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
and K(6) should be 0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0 or 0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0....

My Solution

```
     Array: 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   1  1  0  0
     Index: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19  20 21 22 23
     Sum:   1 2 2 3 4 4 5 6 6  6  6  6  7  7  8  9  9  9  9  10 11 11 11
Diff(I-S):  0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3  4  5  6  6  7  7  7  8  9 10  10 10 11 12
```

For K(6)

Start with 9-15 = Store difference in diff.

Next increase difference
8-15(Difference in index)
8-14(Compare Difference in index)

So on keep moving to find element with least elements...

I am looking for better algorithm for this solution.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a *minimal* *contigious*   subarray (otherwise the problem is trivial)

Comment: Yes Amit. I am looking contiguous array...

Comment: It would help to also mention "smallest" in the body of your question, and change "smallest subset" to "shortest substring" in the question title.

Comment: It is not a string, I have an array with me... So I will need subset only..

Comment: All "string" means is "contiguous sequence of elements".  "Subset" does not imply contiguous, so it's currently a misleading title.

Comment: Okay, I have modified the title, hope that will make more sense now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you could do it with a rolling window like:

1. In the given array, find the first occurance of 0 (say at index `i`).
2. Keep on scanning until you've `k` 0's included in your window (say, the window ends at index `j`) Record the window Length(say `j-i+1=L`).
3. Now, discard the left-most 0 at index `i`, and keep scanning till you get next 0 (say at index `i'`
4. Extend the right-end of the window situated at `j` to `j'` to make the count of 0's = `k` again.
5. If the new window-length `L'=j'-i'+1` is smaller update it.

Keep on repeating the above procedure till `j` hits the end of array.

No extra space needed and It's `O(N)` time-complexity, as an element would be scanned at max twice.

Answer (score 1):

With extra O(k) memory , you can do it in O(n) time.Here is the java code.What you are doing is , if a[i]==0 then you check where the queue's first element points to.and if the differnce in positions is less than minimum, then you update the answer.

```
Queue<Integer> queue =new LinkedList<Integer>();
int i=0;
while(queue.size()<k&&i<n)
{
if(a[i]==0)
{
queue.add(i);
}
i++;
}
if(i==n&&queue.size()<k)
System.out.println("Insufficient 0''s");
int ans=i-1-queue.peek();
for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
{
if(a[i]==0)
{
queue.poll();
queue.add(i);
ans=Math.min(ans,i-queue.peek());
}
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

EDIT :Explanation

We maintain a queue which consist of all the positions which have a 0 and we limit the queue size to be k. So initially in the while loop we fill the queue with the first k indexes. If ofcourse the queue size is less than k after seeing all elements , then it's impossible.  After that , we keep going to all the left over elements .Each time we see a 0 , we calcualte the length of the subsequence ,(i-queue.peek()) and find the minimum .Also we remove the first element , and add the latest index again maintaining the queue size

Comment: @Vishal :I have updated the code with explanation.Does it now make sense to u ?

Answer (score 1):

fully working python code:

```
>>> A = "1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   1  1  0  0".split()
>>> A = map(int, A)
>>> zero_positions = [i for i, x in enumerate(A) if x == 0]
>>> k = 3
>>> containing_k_zeros_intervals = zip(zero_positions, zero_positions[k:])
>>> min(b - a for a, b in containing_k_zeros_intervals)
3
```

Comment: If you wanted to extract the interval rather than just its length, change b - a to (a, b)

Comment: wouldn't taking the min of (a,b) produce the minimum pair in lexicographical order?

Comment: Something like min([(a, b) for a, b in containing_k_zeros_intervals], key = lambda (a, b): b-a) instead?

Comment: sorry, I meant change b - a to (b - a, a, b). Thanks for noticing wye.bee :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Scan the array from the starting to find the index till which we get k zeros.

Have two pointers.

Now ptr1 is at the index where first zero is seen.
start = ptr1

ptr2 is at the index where we have found k 0's.

end = ptr2;
 a)increment ptr1.

b ) find the index from ptr2+1 until we find k 0's.

c) Say at ptr3 we find K 0's. If ptr3-ptr1 < (end-start)  update indexes start and end.

Repeat steps a -c until the end of the list.

At the end, start and end will have indexes where there are k 0's.